# Is there any value in the "testcase" tag?

Tags: discussion

Here, in the SQA site, a tag should help narrow down your search results.  Is it likely that anyone will search for "testcase"?  My opinion: it's not specific enough and we should delete it, and in any cases where it is the only tag, replace it with something more specific.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for replacement?

Comment: I suggest using tags that are more specific to the question.  If you have a testcase written in Java, tag it with Java.  If you have a testcase about banking, tag it with banking.

Answer (score -2):

Do your results contain a variety of different types of data, of which "testcase" is a subset?  If they do, then there could be some value.  Typically though, when dealing with a set of test results, they will have been generated as a consequence of test cases, therefore the tag has no value.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question wasn't clear.  I'm referring to the tags we attach to questions in SQA, here, on this site.